# ASP.NET, cross site Session state

Tags: .net, asp.net, session-state

I need to figure out a way to check if a session in a site is up or not.

i mean:
I have two application that run on the same IIS.
In a page of the first app there's an iFrame in witch lies a page given by the second app...
the problem is that any postback or async calls ont the iframe doesn't reset the second app  timeout.

I tried doing a request clientside on the 'readystatechanged' event, but it works only for the postbacks and not for the asyncs. I'm wandering if there is a 'polling' way to check the Session state of the iFrame application from the main page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own session state provider that stores the session in a in a SQL database or some other external storage. Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588.aspx